# How can I insert into a Postgres table with a unique constraint without waiting on concurrent transactions?

Tags: postgresql, insert, concurrency, unique-constraint, blocking

I have a table like this in a Postgres database:

```
CREATE TABLE tabwithunique (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    key BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    value BIGINT NOT NULL
);
```

I want to design a statement that allows concurrent transactions to insert into this table without *blocking* on the unique constraint.

Instead, I would like "try-lock"-like behavior: I would like the insert to immediately return if a concurrent transaction is currently attempting to insert another row with the same `key`.

I tried using `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, but it seems that Postgres still waits on concurrent transactions (so that it can return whether or not the insert succeeded):

| Transaction 1 | Transaction 2 |
| --- | --- |
| `BEGIN;` |  |
|  | `BEGIN;` |
| `INSERT INTO tabwithunique (key, value)` `VALUES (100, 111)` `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;` → INSERT 0 1 |  |
|  | `INSERT INTO tabwithunique (key, values)` `VALUES (100, 222)` `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;` **(blocks)** — this is what I DON'T want to happen. > I WANT this to immediately return INSERT 0 0. |

I want to avoid unnecessary blocking, and I would instead like the second insert to immediately return, indicating that the insert failed due to another row with the same `key`, even though the other row is not yet committed. These transactions will be retried, so even if the other transactions ends up rolling-back, the row will eventually be inserted.

I'm running Postgres 13.9 with the default `READ COMMITTED` transaction isolation level.

Ideally, I would like an answer that works when inserting many rows at the same time using a insert-query like `INSERT INTO tabwithunique (SELECT ......`

Answer (score 3):

You should

```
SET LOCAL lock_timeout = '1ms';
```

before you attempt the `INSERT`. Then you would get an error message if there is a lock conflict. Then you would get an error `lock_not_available` (SQLSTATE `55P03`) if there is a conflict, which you can handle in your application.

Your comments suggest that you want to insert several rows in a single transaction. Then you don't want to abort the transaction if there is a conflict. For that, you can set savepoints before an `INSERT`, so that you can rollback to the savepoint in case of an error:

```
BEGIN;

SET LOCAL lock_timeout = '1ms';

SAVEPOINT a;

INSERT ...;

SAVEPOINT a;

INSERT ...;

COMMIT;
```

Whenever you encounter an error caused by a lock timeout, you `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT a;`. **But don't use more than 64 savepoints in a transaction**, because [that will lead to performance problems](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/subtransactions-and-performance-in-postgresql/).

Comment: I think that will work for a single row. Is there a way to make this work if I am inserting many rows in a single transaction? I don't want to rollback the entire transactiin, just skip the individual rows which I couldn't lock

Comment: You seem to be suffering from a disease called "long transactions". Cure that, and the whole problem will disappear.

Comment: Sometimes long transactions are out of your control. For example, if your clients are running on the JVM, it's impossible to completely eliminate long JVM pauses. I don't expect there to be long-running transactions, but I want a solution that can tolerate them.

Comment: I doubt that you cannot avoid long delays, even with Java. But be that as it may, I added something to the answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

One approach I found uses Postgres's support for explicit ["advisory locks"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS).

While the row-level locks don't seem to support "try-lock" behavior for pending inserts, an explicit call to `pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(unique_key)` could be used to insert in a non-blocking way.

```sql
INSERT INTO tabwithunique (key, value)
SELECT * FROM (.......) to_insert
WHERE pg_try_advisory_xact_lock($LOCKING_NAMESPACE_VALUE, to_insert.key)
```

This has some drawbacks:

- Advisory locks only support locking one 64-bit key, or two 32-bit keys. This means you will need to convert your `UNIQUE` column into a small integer.
- It also doesn't have any built-in support for namespacing; all uses of advisory locks are locking in the same space. To avoid different uses of advisory locks conflicting, you can use one 32-bit value as the "namespace".
- Because advisory locks are *explicit*, it requires cooperation from other inserters.